# iOS: typewriter style effect

Tags: ios, string, stringtokenizer

I'd like to get the letters of a text appear as they where written on a typewriter; in other words I would like to read a source text file and display it letter after letter on the string forming sentences.

Example:

[1] H
[2] He
[3] Hel
[4] Hell
[5] Hello

Where the [ ] represents the seconds and the second part what's displayed on screen.

In other words It is a sort of string reader and tokenizer which displays letter after letter. Is there already some useful library out there or do approach I have in mind is a good one?

Algorithm:
- load the source text file
- break it in characters and display them with a certain delay (e.g. 0.1s) (to display it could be as simple as appending them to the previous string)

Comment: What have you tried? A timer coupled to a `UILabel`? Anything else? What doesn't work?

Comment: I hate to just drop links like that, but: https://github.com/lexrus/LTMorphingLabel

Comment: Timer and UILable gives me a basic animation (e.g. the character do not "fly" towards the end of the string but instead simply appear). I am wondering if someone had done a library to create this sort of animation so I do not have to re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: Anyway.. I appraciete u hate doing so but the link u sent is actually very useful and saved me a ton of additional work. I was not able to find it as I had searched the wrong things on google. So thank you for the contribution.